# how to take a value from a function with arguments?

Tags: html, angular

```
<input [value]="firstName">
```

binds the value of the input to `firstName`

what If I want the firstName to be returned but with an agrument, how do I do that?

```
<input [value]="firstName('myarg here')"> <!-- what is the syntax to do that -on angular2 ->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly like your are already doing.

That function has to be in your component.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <input [value]="firstname('test', 333, ['a', 'b'])"/>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  firstname(a1: string, a2: number, a3: any[]) {
    return 'firstname ' + a1 + a2 + a3.join(',');
  }
}
```

live demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/799pNvuibWdJoyAwxxfl?p=preview